# How can I avoid travis-ci "SSL errors"?

Tags: r, ssl, travis-ci

I am using travis-ci for building and testing an R package that accesses a RESTful API. Building, checking, and using outside of the travis infrastructure appears to work fine.  However, when building on travis, I get:

```
SSL connect error
Execution halted
```

Travis build log details are [here](https://travis-ci.org/seandavi/GenomicDataCommons).

I have seen multiple reports of similar problems over the years that appear to do with either missing or outdated certs.  The most recent report of a problem appears to suggest an [older version of openSSL on travis](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41292493/ssl-certificate-failure-on-travis-but-works-fine-locally-using-requests-and-ce).

Any suggestions on fixes or how to proceed with troubleshooting?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks to the Travis support team on Twitter the answer is to install an upgraded version of ssl. In your `.travis.yml` file include:

```
addons:
  apt:
    packages:
      - libssl1.0.0
```